# Is a continuous-to-categorical functional dependency a violation of 3NF?

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, 3nf

Let's say I have a table in my database with attributes:

**{ int *Student_Id* (primary key), float *Grade*, category *Level* }**,

where the category of the ***Level*** variable is completely determined by the ***Grade*** via a piecewise function. Something like:

***Level*** = "*Top*" if 90 <= ***Grade*** <= 100;

"*High*" if 80 <= ***Grade*** < 90;

"*Basic*" if 60 <= ***Grade*** < 80; and

"*Low*" if 0 <= ***Grade*** <60.

Obviously there is a functional dependency between non-key attributes (***Grade -> Level***), which appears to be a 3NF violation. To eradicate that dependency, I would have to create a new table **{ *Grade, Level* }**, but that table would be practically infinite, because the grades can have any real value between 0 and 100.

Also, the variable ***Level*** is very important, so I don't want to do without it in my database, having to "*calculate*" it every time I need it.

Is there an *official* way to deal with this type of dependency?

Comment: Your title title & posts ask different questions. "that table would be practically infinite" Why? Why not use a projection, which normalization gives? Or have a computed attribute; the table violates 3NF, but that isn't a problem because the DBMS manages the values. Or call a function in a query. PS We can expect this is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. [ask]

Comment: Actually, my question and some good answers are here. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/247095/does-a-computed-column-break-3nf-third-normal-form
I researched looking for answers but have not found them since I did not know the concept of "computed attributes", totally new for me. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to know specific terms, you just need to write "clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal". Your post doesn't contain one either. Good luck.